# Finding Solution to $\frac{dy}{dx} = x(y − 2)^2 − 2,$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x(y − 2)^2 − 2,$$
with initial condition $(0, 2)$

Comment: dy / dx = x(y − 2)^2 − 2 this is the correct equation

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  What have you tried?

Comment: I don't think this has a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change of variable should do the job. Let $z=y-2$, then
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dx}$$

Comment: Isn't this totally trivial? Of course the derivative of $y-2$ is the same as the derivative of $y$.

Comment: You meant $z$, and yes, but the OP might not know how to do change of variable.